# Loading pages is extremely slow in dev mode in Next.js (30s+), what could be causing this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js

**QUESTION:**

Running into the following issue essentially (but with different files) : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17977

Tried everything suggested there already.

Here is what a page load looks like in dev mode:

[image]

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to optimise this?

---

**CODE:**

**next.config.js:**

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const webpack = require("webpack")
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
})
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['swr']);

nextConfig = {
    images: {
        domains: ['storage.googleapis.com'],
    },
    webpack: config => {
        config.resolve.extensions = [ '.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.json' ];
        config.plugins.push(
            new webpack.ProgressPlugin((percentage, message, ...args) => {
                // e.g. Output each progress message directly to the console:
                console.info(percentage, message, ...args);
            })
        );
        return config
    }
}

module.exports = withPlugins([
    withBundleAnalyzer,
    withTM
], nextConfig);
```

Tried commenting out everything in next.config.js before doing npm run dev but did not change anything.

**js.config.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": [
    "/node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3222",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
    "analyze:server": "cross-env BUNDLE_ANALYZE=server next build",
    "analyze:browser": "cross-env BUNDLE_ANALYZE=browser next build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@iconify/icons-ant-design": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-eva": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-ic": "^1.1.3",
    "@iconify/react": "^1.1.4",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.34",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^5.0.0-alpha.34",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.34",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^5.0.0-alpha.33",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^11.0.1",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.5",
    "apexcharts": "^3.27.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.21.1",
    "emoji-mart": "^3.0.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.9.0",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "millify": "^4.0.0",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^8.0.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-load-script": "^0.0.6",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.2",
    "react-tradingview-widget": "^1.3.2",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.35.2",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.0",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.0",
    "swr": "^0.5.6"
  }
}
```

---

**BUNDLE ANALYSIS:**

**Client**
[image]
[image]

**Server**
[image]
[image]

---

**WEBPACK PROGRESS PLUGIN OUTPUT AND OTHER TERMINAL OUTPUT:**

https://pastebin.com/PAfudkdg

---

**ERROR WHEN DOING NPM INSTALL:**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: fintex@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-tradingview-widget
npm ERR!   react-tradingview-widget@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

---

**TERMINAL OUTPUT WHEN DOING NPM INSTALL --FORCE:**

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   14 more (@emotion/react, @emotion/styled, @material-ui/core, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-tradingview-widget
npm WARN   react-tradingview-widget@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   5 more (@material-ui/core, @material-ui/lab, framer-motion, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.0.0" from react-tradingview-widget@1.3.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-tradingview-widget
npm WARN   react-tradingview-widget@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   14 more (@emotion/react, @emotion/styled, @material-ui/core, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0" from simplebar-react@2.3.5
npm WARN node_modules/simplebar-react
npm WARN   simplebar-react@"^2.3.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   5 more (@material-ui/core, @material-ui/lab, framer-motion, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0" from simplebar-react@2.3.5
npm WARN node_modules/simplebar-react
npm WARN   simplebar-react@"^2.3.0" from the root project
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated react-load-script@0.0.6: abandoned and unmaintained

added 621 packages, and audited 622 packages in 55s

73 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Does `rm -rf .next node_modules package-lock.json` and then `npm install` help? Sometimes it could just be due to bad cache

Comment: I just tried again. Unfortunately, it did not change anything :/ I do have to do npm i --legacy-peer-deps instead of npm i though, could that have had any impact ? (I would imagine not based on what I read, but can never be 100% sure)

Comment: Interesting, maybe do `npm install --force` instead of  `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`?

Comment: Going to try that again now (had also tried some time ago if I remember correctly, but better be sure)

Comment: @PsyGik Problem persists unfortunately. Updated question with error for npm install and terminal output for npm install --force

Comment: Looks like `react-tradingview-widget` has a react dependency mismatch. Can you try installing it separately after installing the other dependencies?

Comment: Is it possible that the SSR server is waiting for some kind of call (like an axios request to an API) to complete, and doesn't serve the page until it has timed out after 30 seconds?

Comment: @PsyGik Just did that (for simplebar-react as well because had conflict as well), instealled them (with --force again because had to) after installing the rest. The issue is still there unfortunately.

Comment: @Joshua Using console.time('ssr') (at beginning of getStaticProps) and console.timeEnd('ssr') (at end of getStaticProps) to check how long it takes for getStaticProps to run (which includes axios requests). Got times that were a tiny fraction of the 30+ seconds it took for the page to load, so the issue might not be there. (just tried again: got ssr: 1.984s) (getStaticProps was getServerProps before, hence why "ssr" is being used the console.time)

Comment: Try to use `lazy load` for loading components...

Comment: Are you use npm 7? `npm -v`
If so try downgrading to npm 6

`npm i -g npm@6`

Then do
`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
`npm i`

Comment: Which browser are you on? I noticed I have this issue with Google Chrome (Canary). When I use Firefox, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @andykenward Using npm 7.18.1, need to double check if I need version 7

Comment: @MaximZubarev  I typically use Chrome. Issue is also present on Firefox unfortunately.

Comment: @TheProgrammer could you also tell us about the environment you're running it in? e.g. Are you running this in a docker container vs vm vs  bare metal? do you have multiple NICs?

Comment: @ArcaArtem Running locally on my laptop

Comment: I would suggest creating a blank app, try if it works and then add your dependencies one by one, checking the current latest stable version of each, some are causing dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to separate the dependencies with devDependencies

like these packages are should be inside devDependencies

```
prop-types @next/bundle-analyzer cross-env next-compose-plugins next-transpile-modules
```

and I think you can remove

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['swr']);
```

from the next.config.js -- but not sure it will give you errors or not, I have never put swr into transpile modules before.

and for loading 3rd parties script, try using the new next11  component, rather than using other libraries (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script)

other that that, I would recommend that you can remove react-icons and use the iconify/eva for the replacement - It is just to reduce same usage library..

Cheers man . It is a hard to optimize loading time and speed for dev or production nevertheless.. can't never be too cautious for any opportunities to improve it.